# Upload files via JavaScript without reloading the web page?

Tags: javascript

What are basic steps to upload multiply files via JavaScript without reloading the web page?

Answer (score 1):

ajax doesn't support file upload, you would need to use a hidden iframe or flash.
I recommend using one of the existing libraries for this.

Comment: Several finished examples exist: http://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&q=ajax+file+upload

Answer (score 0):

Post a form to a hidden iframe.